# How to make a C++ wrapper to provide file and line information for a std::vector out of range message on terminal and abort

Tags: c++, stl

How to make a C++ wrapper to provide file and line information for a std::vector out of range message on terminal and abort?

I wrote the attached code, which does the job, but needed the extra template R, which is used to output the result that to get it to compile.

Two questions :-

1. Is there any way avoid using a MACRO to get the file and line info passed so it can be output?
2. Is there a way to change it so I could change so the function returns the item? ie std::string s = vec_get(v, idx);

This is the current output, which is clearer than just the stl_vector.h _M_range_check output (this is the STL library)

```
$ ./vec_throw2
vec_throw2.cpp:69 err std::vector 0 out of range size 0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
what():  vec_get
Aborted (core dumped)



The code follows

// g++ -Wall -O2 -o vec_throw vec_throw2.cpp
#include <vector>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

template<class T, class R>
void vec_get(T v, R r, size_t idx, const char * const file, const int line)
{
    if (idx<v.size())
    {
        r = v.at(idx);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s:%d err std::vector %zu out of range size %zu\n", file, line, idx, v.size());
        throw std::out_of_range ("vec_get");
    }
}

#define VEC_GET2(v, w, idx) vec_get(v, w, idx, __FILE__, __LINE__)

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    int ret = 0;
    size_t idx = 0;

    std::string s;
    VEC_GET2(v, s, idx);
    return ret;
}
```

I experimented with some different ways, including 'auto' return.

Comment: if you can use c++20 https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location.

Comment: i would consider writing your application code so that it checks for size, and at least replace the call to at in your template, which can never fail, with operator[]. better to deal with problems at the highest possible level.

Comment: I dont understand the issue with 2. What problem did you encounter when returning the element rather than using an out parameter?

Comment: Either use `std::fprintf(stderr, ...` instead of `printf` or add `std::fflush(stdout);` after your `printf`

Comment: If you want to use an out parameter make that a reference, or this will not work. But I suggest returning the answer. If you want to return the a string in case of faliure I suggest `std::variant<string,R>` as a return type.

Answer (score 3):

Using `std::source_location` and just checking the bounds once:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <source_location>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <vector>

template <class T, class R>
void vec_get(T v, R& r, size_t idx, // take r by reference
             const std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current()) {
    try {
        r = v.at(idx); // only one bounds check
    } catch (...) {
        // If you use `printf` you may need to `std::fflush(stdout)` to see your
        // message. Use `fprintf(stderr, ...` or `std::cerr` instead.
        std::cerr << loc.file_name() << ':' << loc.line() << " err std::vector "
                  << idx << " out of range size " << v.size() << '\n';
        throw;  // rethrow the original exception
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v;
    size_t idx = 0;
    std::string s;

    vec_get(v, s, idx);

    std::cout << s << '\n';
}
```

Possible output:

```
example.cpp:23 err std::vector 0 out of range size 0
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

In c++20 you can use `std::source_location`. Though afaik only `gcc` supports it. Then you do not need the macro.

Actually I don't know what issue you encountered with returning the element. You can just do it ;)

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <source_location>
        
using namespace std;

template<class V>
auto vec_get(V v, size_t idx, std::source_location loc = std::source_location::current()) {
    if (idx >= v.size()) {
        std::cout << loc.file_name() << " " 
                  << loc.line() << " "
                  << idx << " " 
                  << v.size() << std::endl;
        throw std::out_of_range ("vec_get");
    }
    return v[idx];
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> v;

    int ret = 0;
    size_t idx = 0;

    std::string s = vec_get(v, idx);
    return ret;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Tr1z91j5b)

As mentioned in comments, once you checked that the index is valid and throw your own exception there is no point in calling `at`. Also you have to make sure to flush the stream before throwing the exception if you want to see output also when the program terminates.

---

However, I do allow myself to question your approach. Instead of getting used to try accessing element via invalid index, you should rather make sure that indices are valid before actually trying to access the element. It is really rare that you cannot do that. From the top of my head the only instance I can imagine is when the index is from external input. And in this case you would implement some sanity checks on the input rather than relying on the container to throw some `out_of_range` error that tells nothing about the root cause.

On the other hand, there are many cases where you do not want bounds checking. For example it would be a waste in a loop iterating the elements:

```
for (int i=0; i < v.size(); ++i) vec_get(v,i); // please no!
```

Comment: Thank you for all the replies everyone. That std::source_location is very useful, it's interesting it doesn't return the file and line of the vec_get() function. It returns the file and line when vec_get() was called.

fprintf to stderr is a great tip, thank you.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions about the approach. Yes I agree making sure indices are valid is really important.

I was looking at some user feedback after they saw the _M_range_check message and I wanted to get some file and line info in my build for them.

Occasionally a situation where a programmer uses operator[idx] occurs, and that one isn't detected unless I supply a build with Santizer... so I was thinking to change to get_vec() style which calls at(idx) because I would rather have a meaningful message on the terminal at least.

Comment: Re my question (2) If I change to have R return, and even call the function directly (no more macro) I get compile errors:

template<class T, class R>
R vec_get(T v, size_t idx, const char * const file, const int line)

vec_throw4.cpp:51:16: error: no matching function for call to ‘vec_get(std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&, size_t&, const char [15], int)’
   51 |     s = vec_get(v, idx, __FILE__, __LINE__);
      |         ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

vec_throw4.cpp:18:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class T, class R> R vec_get(T, size_t, const char*, int)’

Comment: 18 | R vec_get(T v, size_t idx, const char * const file, const int line)
      |   ^~~~~~~
vec_throw4.cpp:18:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
vec_throw4.cpp:51:16: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘R’
   51 |     s = vec_get(v, idx, __FILE__, __LINE__);
      |         ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Comment: @rich the compiler error is because there is no way to deduce `R`. There is no need  for it to be a template argument in the firest place. The return type is `T::value_type`

Comment: Great, this works like this:
 template<class T>
typename T::value_type vec_get(T v, size_t idx, const char * const file, const int line)